# Jenkins Security - Unable to login

Tags: jenkins

I enabled security on Jenkins and added myself as the only user. After clicking on "Save" it brought me back to the log-on screen without asking me to create a password. Now I can not log-in with the username I just added. Is there a default password that I can use or do I have to disable security again in the config.xml file?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: This questioned was answered in this link from Jenkins community
https://community.jenkins.io/t/cant-login-to-jenkins-installation-wizard/1166

Answer (score 49):

I solved it. Here's what I did.

1. I disabled security in `JENKINS_HOME/config.xml`
2. Restarted Tomcat
3. I re-enabled security
4. Selected Jenkin's own database and also checked Allow users to Sign-up
   (Also make sure that in Authorization, "Anyone can do anything" is ticked.)
5. "Save". After clicking Save, it will bring you to the initial page, then on the top-right corner there is a "Sign up" link.
6. Click on "Sign up", enter your username and password then log-in. Right now you are the only registered user. But it actually did something else. Prior to the creation of your first account, there is no "Manage users" in the "Manage Jenkins" menu. I saw this guide on adding users to Jenkins and it says that there should be a "Manage users" link under the "Manage Jenkins" menu but there is none. But after you have created your first account (using Sign up), you can now find it there.
7. Add users on the "Manage users" and then go back to "Manage security" then disable "Allow users to sign up". Also, you can now use Matrix based authentication without having to worry about getting locked out of Jenkins.

I hope someone can find this useful.

Cheers.

Comment: #4 should start with "navigate to the GUI, select Manage Jenkins, select Configure Global Security, in Access Control...."

Comment: How did you do #1?  I set useSecurity from true to false.  Restarted nginx with "sudo systemctl reload nginx".  Then set useSecurity back to true.  Went to ipaddress:8080 and its still asking for a username and password.  /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword no longer exists.  Something deleted it and it wasn't me.  Can't believe the lack of documentation!

Answer (score 16):

1. http://localhost:8080/
2. Put `admin` as user and `admin password` as a password, your admin password is the one you got while installing jenkins. In-case you forgot your admin password:

   ```
   Goto-> `/Users/{your
   username}/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`
   ```

Comment: this is the real answer

Comment: Glad that it helped, please mark as accepted

Answer (score 2):

When u download the .msi file, we have issues with logging in. The password cannot be found at the location /jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword. So it is advisible to download the generic java package (.war file) from https://jenkins.io/download/

Then go to the Jenkins location in the command prompt and execute the command "java -jar jenkins.war"

After few minutes, at the end of installation and initialization of Jenkins it gives a temporary password. Copy it and now you can access Jenkins at http://localhost:8080 and enter the temporary password

Answer (score 1):

Fine Jenkins_home 
open config.xml inside home directory.
find useSecurity tag - and set it default. restart Jenkins.
Open Jenkins (should take you inside with out a user name and password) -- go to manage jenkins -> Global Security -> Enable Sign up -> sign up a new user -> once user is sign up - login with that user and finally enable login and restart your jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to this path 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword.txt

Open this copy the password

Access the jenkins login url :http://localhost:8080/

Enter the below credentials

---

User name  : admin
  password   : copy and paste the password that you have in
               C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword.txt

Comment: what about the username?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and googled it for a whole day trying different things to no avail.  I finally had to re-install the whole thing.  Just remember to store the original admin password when you configure Jenkins. Otherwise you'll never be able to log back in.

Answer (score 0):

ttp://localhost:8080/
Put admin as user and admin password as a password, your admin password is the one you got while installing jenkins. In-case you forgot your admin password:
Get it from C:\Users\.jenkins\secrets\InitialAdminPassword

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the same error while login, you need to go to the server cd /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initial password

copy that in Jenkins Login page