# jenkins does not allow to login, login page reappears

Tags: jenkins

In our company, we are using Jenkins as our CI tool.  But from few days, we are facing issue during jenkins login.  The login page re-appears for some users and it does not allow them to login to jenkins.  These users are there in the system from long time and they are not new users nor they have entered wrong password. They have tried several times, but it does not allow them to login. What could be the issue?? Any help?
Users are authenticated through atlassian crowd.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312010/jenkins-security-unable-to-login

Answer (score 0):

It seems cookies/chaches are a problem.  Deleting the cookies for jenkins solves the problem in the browser.  Opened a tab in incognito mode and then I am able to login.