# How to create Jenkins credentials

Tags: jenkins

Creation of Jenkins credentials for second time accessing Jenkins site(localhost:8080):

First time I entered into Jenkins, but i am new , so i didn't configure(or create) Jenkins credentials, from second time on wards it is asking username and password to sign-in.but i didn't create.
how to get username and password?Actually I tried with admin/first time password, but still it is not working.and I tried with troubleshoot to enter into jenkins site, it is also not working.

Note:I am working in windows platform.

Comment: I am using latest jenkin version as of now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312010/jenkins-security-unable-to-login

Comment: no, I am not able to enter jenkin's site itself.It is always asking userid/password.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution.admin is initial userid and password is goto this path:/jenkins/secrets/initialadminpassword file, you will have password.That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not set Jenkins initial credential then it will be

```
username: admin
password: Go to your jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword for password.
```