# Can not log into Jenkins - invalid username or password?

Tags: jenkins

I'm running `jenkins/jenkins:lts` and configured global security to use "Unix user/group database".

So I log in as root in my Docker container

```
$ docker exec -u 0 -it c63ae5e44d6e bash
```

and create a user, and add it to the Jenkins group

```
$ useradd myUser
$ usermod -aG jenkins myUser
$ passwd myUser (and provide a password)
```

Now when I try to log in, I get "Invalid username or password", and I see this in the logs

```
unix_chkpwd[207]: check pass; user unknown
unix_chkpwd[208]: check pass; user unknown
unix_chkpwd[208]: password check failed for user (myUser)
```

Any clues? TIA

Answer (score 0):

The answer with the most votes in [Jenkins Security - Unable to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312010/jenkins-security-unable-to-login) at least enabled me to set a working security configuration. If someone can directly answer the question then I'll accept their answer.